# What is the name of this view or projection?

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces

I am looking for help with the math terminology to describe the following concept.

Consider I live in a 2D universe shaped as a 2-sphere. I am at the North Pole looking down along the meridians. I see the South Pole in every direction, so it appears to me as a circle. What I see is not a globe, but a disk centered on me, and my view is distorted in such a way that, for example, I see a single point of the South Pole as a full circle.

What is the name of the mathematical concept describing this view? Is it a map or projection or any sort of morphism or anything else?

I’d like to learn more about this concept and would appreciate if someone points me in the right direction. Thank you!

Comment: You're thinking about geodesic polar coordinates centered at the north pole. The circle of radius $\pi$ centered at the origin collapses to the south pole.

Comment: @TedShifrin Hi Ted and thanks for your insight! I can use this term to search for more information, but I wonder if you have any links to good references.

Comment: This is standardly in most differential geometry texts (although not my own). I don't know your background, so it's hard to make recommendations. (Certainly it's in doCarmo's undergraduate text, and in lots of others.)

Comment: @TedShifrin Can you possibly point me to a page or section in doCarmo? My objective is to see if this representation is the same (or at least similar) for a static spherical space and for an expanding flat space. For the lack of the math terminology my question was misinterpreted as physics and downvoted, so I had to delete it. Now I am trying to learn the terminology to phrase that question better. In the meantime, could you possibly take a look? You should be able to see it: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3530891/ - I would hugely appreciate any feedback, answer, or suggestion!